# How to enable email and password signin provider for new firebase project using gcloud console or firebase tools CLI?

Tags: firebase-authentication, gcloud, firebase-tools

In the company I am working for, we provide a solution for other companies, and we want each company to have a separate instance of that solution, this includes a separate database instance, the database is Firebase, this choice of creating a new separate instance is required due to data privacy laws of the country we work in.

I am working on a script that when triggered by the new client SignUp, it starts the creation of new solution instance, including the creation of the new `Firebase` project, and I am using `firebase-tools CLI` and `gcloud CLI`.

The project creation happens correctly, and the admin account is created, the only remaining thing is to allow the admin to be able to login to the new `Firebase` project. This is usually done manually from the `Firebase web console`, by enabling a login provider, an `Email&Password` login provider in my case. This part of the process is so not automated, because I can't find the command that I should pass to `Firebase-tools` or `gcloud ClI` to enable a login provider in a `Firebase` project.

What is a command that you can pass to `Firebase tools` or to `gcloud CLI` , to change firebase project confguration to enable a signin provider ? signin usng `Email&Passsword` in this case .. Or is there a way to do it programmatically using `Google client libraries` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the [REST API for the Google Identify Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2), I don't immediately see a call that shows email+password authentication. Unless I'm overlooking something this means it might not be possible to programmatically enable this provider through a public API.

From checking what the Firebase console does, it seems it handles the provider configuration through the `https://identitytoolkit.clients6.google.com/admin/v2/projects/<projectid>/config` endpoint, but I'm not sure that is part of the public API.

Answer (score 1):

This seems possible now via [Identity Toolkit API](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest). The v2.projects REST resource has [updateConfig](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/updateConfig) method, and the Config contains SignInConfig which have the [Email](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/Config#Email) property.